# Redshift auto-increment does not work start negative number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, auto-increment

I would like to insert in my dimensions special records where the identifier would be negative to differentiate from the normal records. For example: -2 -> Not Applicable, -1 -> Not Found, etc ...

My table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
id BIGINT IDENTITY (-2,1),
des VARCHAR (10)
);

INSERT INTO test (des) values ('reg-2');
INSERT INTO test (des) values ('reg-1');
INSERT INTO test (des) values ('reg 0');
INSERT INTO test (des) values ('reg 1');

select * from test order by id;
id    |  des
-----------------------
-2    reg-2
-1    reg-1
 0    reg 0
 6    reg 1
```

I would like the identifier field to continue incrementing by 1 in 1.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: You have found an undocumented feature / bug. suggest you report to AWS as this is a valid use case for dimension tables.

Comment: Redshift IDENTITY column values are guaranteed to be unique, but not necessarily consecutive. For example the COPY command can produce non-consecutive ranges of identity values. Possibly something about the preceding negative values is causing Redshift to skip a range of possible identity values when calculating the next identity value.